# Java-best way to check if file contains only null characters

Tags: java, spring, performance, file, null

I'm facing a problem and i can't fix it.
I have a file that is accessible from 2 applications for read and write. when the Device unexpectadly shuts down, the content of the file keep the same size but each character is replaced by Null Character.
Now I need a way to check the content file if is null or not. what is the best performant way to do it?
thank you

Comment: There is no real performant way as the size of the file will determine processing speed. If a file is going to be 20 gigs, it's going to be slow no matter what. Unless you can take a shortcut, like check say at most the first 200 bytes.

Comment: Its unlikely that an unexpected shutdown results in a file being filled with null characters on accident.  If the file was full of null characters that means something had to explicitly write them into the file.  Either way its a really bad idea to have two applications that can read write the same file. If you want concurrent writes to a file you need something like sqlite that can manage the access.  The failure cases are dependent on the file system but mostly result in access issues and or intermixed writes.

Comment: Thank you all for you replies. @Gimby you gave me a great idea to check only a first part of the file.

Comment: @Deadron i can't understand why after shutdown the file content is replaced by NULL characters, i debuggued all possible cases without any result. you are right writing on the same file by differents application is a bad idea but it is how the service is developped.

Comment: By “null characters” you mean zero bytes? Maybe, they are not written over the content but the intended content hadn’t been written in the first place but was residing in a cache.

Answer (score -1):

To perform a check in Java if a file contains only null characters, you can read the file in chunks of bytes and verify if all the bytes in each chunk are zero. Here is how you might go about it using a `BufferedInputStream`:

```java
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(isFileNull("path/to/your/file.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean isFileNull(String filepath) throws IOException {
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filepath))) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++) {
                    if (buffer[i] != 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

- We use `BufferedInputStream` to read the file in chunks.
- Inside the `isFileNull` method, we read chunks of the file into a byte array buffer using the `read` method, which returns the number of bytes read or -1 if the end of the stream is reached.
- We then iterate over each byte in the buffer and check if any of them are non-zero using a simple comparison (`buffer[i] != 0`). If we find any non-zero bytes, we return `false` immediately.
- If we reach the end of the file without finding any non-zero bytes, we return `true`.
- Note that we are using a try-with-resources statement to ensure that the `BufferedInputStream` is closed properly, even if an exception is thrown.

Comment: This code is needlessly complicated. The point of `BufferedInputStream` is that you can call `read()` (as in, the no-args one that returns a single byte) efficiently. You're double-buffering: You've wrapped it in a BIS __and__ you using a `byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];`. You only need one of those.  Fix that, plus the minor nit of teaching bad habits, and this downvote can be turned into an upvote.

Comment: The bad habit is `e.printStackTrace();`. That is __toxically__ bad, it needs to be stamped out. The simple fix here is that `main` can, and almost always should, be declared as `throws Exception`. Do that here too. Less code, better code, easier debugging. win-win-win.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this solution then let you know